# Java Applet java.security.AccessControlException?

Tags: java, security, exception, netbeans, applet

When I try to use Group Layout Manager in my applet it gives me this odd exception: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission accessDeclaredMembers)

When I don't use a layout manager (null) it works fine. To see the whole trace dump go to nuevawave.org/sandbox/JavaGallery/GUIApplet.html and right click somewhere in the top left. If I use absolute layout, there is nothing to click on. The jar is at nuevawave.org/sandbox/JavaGallery/GUIApplet.jar. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

I don't know if this will help, but here is the applet code:

```
<applet Archive ="TestApplet.jar,swing-layout-1.0.4.jar"
      Code="test.GUIApplet"
      WIDTH="500" HEIGHT="300"
</applet>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You receive this Exception because the `GroupLayout` uses Reflection (thus the "RuntimePermission accessDeclaredMembers"). Reflection is considered too powerful for *unsigned* applets, so the only chance you have is to either sign your applet or use a different layout manager.

Comment: I used the jarsigner to sign the applet, but I still get the Runtime permission error. Do I have to do something with the html too?

Comment: No, but you have to sign *all* the Jars involved with the same certificate, so you should sign the swing-layout Jar, too.